# From where I can learn Zoomcharts

Tags: zoomcharts

## ZoomCharts Hi, I am new to zoomcharts and i want to learn completely how to make dashboard in zoomchart. From where I can get this information, or to whom I need to connect with for this?

Regards,
Amit

Comment: Have you tried using a service called [Google](http://www.google.com) or - the horror the horror - [looking at the documentation and tutorials](http://www.zoomcharts.com)?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation at: https://zoomcharts.com/en/documentation/

Also there is a forum: https://forum.zoomcharts.com

Finally, you can get training from the ZoomCharts. To get more info, [get in touch](https://zoomcharts.com/en/contacts/) with them.